# Apache Nifi: Invoke URL (not REST) that forces a file download

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a URL which is not REST based, that when hit in a browser, results in the auto-download of a .txt file.

Is there a way to use NiFi to invoke this URL which would result in the download happening on the NiFI server?

Answer (score 0):

Determined that this required the InvokeHttp processor. Works now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).